# How the get all ETH state changes

Tags: go-ethereum

I am writting a data aggregator for DeFi exchanges and I need to collect all historic state changes that occur in certain smart contracts of interest. I suppose one way to do it would be to do a fresh start of the geth client and simply have a script listen for events on the contracts that I am intested in. Obviously, this is not the best because it will take a long time it is hard to extend if I want to gather data from additional contract in the future.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Listening to all state changes can be a very heavy work for the ethereum node you're going to use.
There's a lightweight alternative to only listen to Events emitted by contracts. This would mean that you'll only be able to listen to state changes that the contract developer decided to expose, and not everything in the contract.

You should have a look at The Graph, how [existing subgraphs](https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph?id=84CvqQHYhydZzr2KSth8s1AFYpBRzUbVJXq6PWuZm9U9&view=Overview) index and expose data, and how you could [build your own](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/developing/creating-a-subgraph/) and even [host it inside your infra](https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node).

Comment: Listening to spesific contracts is sufficient. My question is: could I do that without replaying the entire history of transactions? What I need to know is the (exposed) state of each contract of interest after each block. For example, for each Uniswap pair, I want to know the reserves, liquidity etc after each block. AFAIK The graph does  not provide that right?

Comment: you can have a mix of both. Start at a block, fetch all reserves, and for all new blocks only listen to `Sync` events to update the reserves.